# How to make a Tester class?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with making a Tester class for my original code.

So far I have

```
public class BankAccount
{
public BankAccount(double b, String John)
{
    double balance = b;
    String name = John;
}

public double deposit(double balance)
{
    double d = (505.22 + balance);
    return d;
}

public double withdraw(double balance)
{
    double w = (balance - 100);
    return w;
}

public double balance;
public String name;
```

}

Now what I need to do is make a tester class which incorporates the deposit and withdraw method. I'm having trouble coding the Tester class part.
What I have so far:

```
    public class Tester1
    {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    BankAccount myAccount = new BankAccount(1000.00, "John");
    System.out.println( myAccount.deposit(505.22) ); // my error is here. 
}
}
```

the error is "method deposit in class BankAccount cannot be applied to given types; 
rquired: no arguments; found double; reason: actual and formal arguements lists differ in length.

Comment: `error here`, what is the error ?

Comment: "error here" doesn't tell us anything about what's wrong. Is it a compile-time error? An exception? The wrong result? Note that for financial data, `BigDecimal` is more appropriate than `double`.

Comment: What problem? Any specific error?

Comment: What error are you facing? The code looks incorrect to me. The _balance_ variable you have created in constructor is private to constructor. Your program should output - zero! If this is your error then you should take your _balance_ variable's init out of constructor.

Comment: Use unit testing framework for that. TestNG - thats what I am using.

Answer (score 2):

How It compiles ? Your class name is `BankAccountTest`

```
public class BankAccountTest{
```

You are creating object for `BankAccount`

```
BankAccount myAccount = new BankAccount(1000.00, "John");
```

So that  line should be

```
BankAccountTest myAccount = new BankAccountTest(1000.00, "John");
```

**Note:** Shift to better IDE, if you are not using otherwise you end up with solving these type of compile time issues.

Comment: Oh I forgot to remove the Test part, thanks.

Comment: @KevinChu Happy to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are trying to return a value with depoisit which is a setter method. These do not return values

```
    public double deposit(double balance)
{
    double d = (505.22 + balance);
    return d;
}
```

Change this to:

```
    public void deposit(double balance)
{
    double d = (505.22 + balance);
}
```

Then System.out.println the getter that DOES return a value.